# angular + bootstrap tab, not work well for radio

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a simple demo to describe my question, `[link here][1]`
I use angular ng-repeat to create radio, with the same ng-model, different values, the bootstrap tab works well, but the radio not display well, the point of the radio missing when  i click other tab, could anyone help me ?

Thanks for **Marcus's** solution, problem has been solved, but I'm looking for if there has a better idea?

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: link here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh26TOStXcNObBtiBc5t?p=preview

Comment: @Marcus I add the link in the comment, stackoverflow not allowed me to put the plnkr link, I don't know how to add this in my question content

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add more Angular to the mix:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gV88Lrh7Xc6xqkF9SxCM?p=preview

```html
 <input type="radio" role="tab" ng-model="ajaxSettings.method" value='GET'/>GET

(...)

<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': ajaxSettings.method == 'GET'}"  id="GET"></div>
```

Comment: so it may caused by the bootstrap.js, thanks Marcus, nice solution~

Comment: Better - you mean without removing bootstrap parts?

Comment: yes, i don't like the writing style like 'ng-class="{'active': ajaxSettings.method == 'GET'}"' ..........